# Tool to terminate selected application in Windows

Tags: windows

I'm searching for Windows tool which can induce termination of selected process/application in different way then standard *End Process* button in the *Task Manager*. I'd find it useful for

- testing my own applications
- killing some protected applications like Symantec AV Scanner (if it takes 40% CPU but is configured by policies to prevent exiting)

Comment: I use taskkill.exe that ships with Windows. It also has a /f force option.

Comment: But it does the same as *Task Manager* so it doesn't answer original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Advanced Process Termination](http://www.testmypcsecurity.com/securitytests/advanced_process_termination.html)** does the job well.

It can kill selected application in several polite ways (various types of termination requests) as well as using some brutal crashes caused by injected code.

Do not forget to run the tool **as Administrator**.

This tool still cannot kill [unkillable applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988/really-killing-a-process-in-windows), there is no way to kill them.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Being a Linux user only using a Windows machine when forced to (e.g. at work), I prefer the command-line tools I'm used to. Though there's no 100% equivalent on Windows, there are at least the **[PSTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx)** offered by MS' own „SysInternals” – according to the page, supported from „Windows XP and higher”.

The kit contains several useful command-line tools. Interesting for your case are mainly [PsList](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682) (to list running processes similarly to the Linux/Unix `ps` command), and [PsKill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683) to terminate processes. You can even use these tools to list/kill processes on a remote Windows machine, if needed. As with the solution [miroxlav proposed](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/11575/185), you might need to specify the Administrator user as the executing one (with the `-u` parameter), and the corresponding password of course (`-p` parameter to the mentioned tools).

As both are command-line tools: Sorry, no fancy screenshot ☺

---

As it turned out in the comments, `pskill` seems not to differ in *functionality*. Moreover, as pointed out in a question on our sister-site StackOverflow<sup>1</sup>, it cannot fulfill the requirement of terminating protected applications. So if this is a must-have, I might instead point to another tool:

**[Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/)** is explicitly reported being able to do that (as pointed out in the last comment on the mentioned question<sup>1</sup>):

[image: Process Hacker]
<sup>*Process Hacker* (source: [Homepage](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/); click image for larger variant)</sup>

The tool further includes graphs and statistics *to track down resource hogs and runaway processes*, helps you find out which process is locking a file you cannot delete, shows active network connections by application, and much more.

Not being a Windows user myself (and currently not even having a Windows machine available), I cannot speak of personal experiences, though. But searching for reviews just found the tool highly praised, as e.g. in [this review of PCWorld](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2031485/review-process-hacker-is-task-manager-on-steroids.html).

---

<sup>**1:** [Terminating a protected antivirus process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11212945/2533433)</sup>

Comment: Is PsKill capable of stopping protected processes? (Process where *End Task* button in Task Manager throws window that this process cannot be stopped.) If not, then I see low added value compared to that *End Task* button.

Comment: That's a question of what user executes it IMHO – which is why I wrote *you might need to specify the Administrator user as the executing one* (using the `-u` and `-p` parameters).

Comment: OK, so from your note I understand you confirm it is capable.

Comment: I have never tried it (no such application here) – but given the Administrator credentials, I cannot see how it should fail. As it's written by the same company that wrote the OS (and further called SysInternals), they should know how the sys internals work I'd say ;)

Comment: You say that *"I cannot see how it should fail"*. Well, [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212945/terminating-a-protected-antivirus-process). How do you know *pskill* is doing something different from *End Process* button in *Task Manager*? I have reasons to think they both do the same. The original question was searching for tool using **different way** of process termination than classic termination of processes.

Comment: I see. But I'm afraid there's no way to find out without trying (I currently do not even have a Windows machine to do so). The linked post from SO seems to suggest there is no way, not even with Admin permissions (which is pretty strange). And you're correct: That post explicitly says even `pskill` failed. Very strange. But the last comment on the question says [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net) shall be able to succeed – maybe you give that one a try?

Comment: Yes, there are more ways to successfully terminate such a process. One of them is the answer I posted. Maybe you can think about modification/removal of your answer in order not no mislead readers because `pskill` is functionally not different from *End Task* button in *Task Manager*. But the question was asking for solutions with **differ** from it. (You can still suggest **Process Hacker** as an answer instead.)

Comment: Done as requested – see updated answer.

Comment: Turned my downvote into an upvote :)

Comment: Glad you like it! Now you just need to pick an answer to accept (two likely candidates, I guess #D)

Comment: OK, I tested Process Hacker on my machine. I choose [APT](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/11575/2336). Process Hacker is great and open source. Still I chose APT because Process Hacker (1) has only one way of termination and APT offers multiple (including crashes), (2) with non-abortable process I can't test Process Hacker right now but the APT is sucessfully tested with it. (3) I think the leftover `pskill` part of the post is still a bit misleading. (It might be at its right place under another question. Maybe you can create another question and put `pskill` as answer there.)

Comment: +1 for the details provided (1+2). I don't think it makes sense to construct another question just to find a place to move a part of the answer to (3), and neither find it too misleading. It's a question of focus, agreed, but IMHO makes perfect sense in this context. Advantages and disadvantages have been pointed out, so things should be clear. Removing that part also would make the comments hard to follow, as it would remove that context along. Thanks a lot for sharing your conclusion!